# How to fix the delay between a user disconnecting and the disconnect event firing on the server with socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, delay

I am trying to build a small lobby system with socket.io, but I recently encountered a problem when a user closes a tab to leave the lobby.
I want to have instant (or at least close to instant) feedback on the client-side when the user disconnects from the lobby.

Unfortunately, it always takes about 35 sec between closing a browser tab and the *socket.on('disconnect')* event firing on the server, which is too long for what I need.

I already did some research and found out, that the connection gets closed instantly when the reason of closure is a *transport close* or a *transport error*.

In my case it seems to be a *ping timeout*, which means that socket.io waits some time until the next package gets sent.
If that doesn't happen, the connection will be closed.

So my question now is, why does the *ping timeout* reason take place here when closing a tab, and how can I change that to a *transport close* reason?

My current code looks like this:

```
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const socketio = require('socket.io');
const formatMessage = require('./utils/messages');
const {
  userJoin,
  getCurrentUser,
  userLeave,
  getRoomUsers
} = require('./utils/users');

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketio(server);

// Run when client connects
io.on('connection', socket => {
  socket.on('joinRoom', ({ username, room }) => {
    const user = userJoin(socket.id, username, room);

    socket.join(user.room);
    console.log("ROOMS AFTER JOIN: ", io.sockets.adapter.rooms);

    // Send users and room info
    io.to(user.room).emit('roomUsers', {
      room: user.room,
      users: getRoomUsers(user.room)
    });
  });

  // Runs when client disconnects
  socket.on('disconnect', (reason) => {
    const user = userLeave(socket.id);
    console.log("Reason: ", reason)

if (user) {
  // Send users and room info
  io.to(user.room).emit('roomUsers', {
    room: user.room,
    users: getRoomUsers(user.room)
  });
}
  });
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

server.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`));
```

Comment: You can add a listener to `beforeunload` event on frontend and close connection from client when it fires.

Comment: @PawanSharma Thanks a lot for your comment. I thought there was another way, but your suggestion works perfectly fine. Thank you.

Comment: Should I add it as an answer so that you can accept it an close the question ?